# Unable to configure ASP.NET HTTPS endpoint in Windows docker container

Tags: powershell, docker, asp.net-core

Getting this error when running ASP.NET Core in Windows docker container...

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found.
```

I was able to get this to work...

```
RUN dotnet dev-certs https
```

But I want to install an actual certificate...for now a self-sign certificate but later a real one.

So based on a blog post titled "Import and bind an SSL cert in a Windows container using Powershell", I created the following PS script to run in the container build...

```
Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath C:\Certificates\xxx.pfx -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String "xxxx" -AsPlainText -Force) `
-CertStoreLocation "Cert:\LocalMachine\My"

$cert = (Get-ChildItem -Path cert:\LocalMachine\My -DNSName "xxx.mydomain.com")[0]

$thumb =  ($cert | Select-Object Thumbprint)."Thumbprint"
$guid = [guid]::NewGuid().ToString("B")

netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:5001 certhash=$thumb certstorename=MY appid="$guid"
```

This builds fine and seems to install the certificate.  But I get the exception when I try to run the container.  I tried using 443 instead of 5001, same error

Here is my docker file for reference...

```
 escape=`
 FROM xxx/base
 EXPOSE 5000
 EXPOSE 5001
 COPY testing/ /testing
 COPY service/ /Service
 COPY certificates/ /certificates
 COPY scripts/ /scripts

 # install certificates

 RUN scripts/Install-Container-Certificate.ps1

 # configure ASP.NET Core

 ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://+:80;https://+:443
 EXPOSE 80
 EXPOSE 443
 # RUN dotnet dev-certs https
 # start ASP.NET Core

 ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","/Service/xxxService.dll"]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not an answer per se, but experiencing same issue, some interesting info here : https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/630 and here https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/6199

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run in Development using a self-signed certificate, you might follow [here](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/master/samples/run-aspnetcore-https-development.md) article. For Production scenarios instead [here](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/master/samples/host-aspnetcore-https.md).

In a nutshell, the suggested approach differs from the one you are using as two volumes could be mounted referencing the folders containing your certificate and your dotnet secrets.

You would map your host "%USER%\.aspnet\https" folder to your guest "/root/.aspnet/https/" and your host "%APPDATA%\microsoft\UserSecrets\" folder to your guest "/root/.microsoft/usersecrets".

The main difference between Production and Development is that in Production you would not use secrets and you will need to pass the folder containing your certificate and the password to access it using the environment variables:

- ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path
- ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password

Kestrel will go looking on your Linux guest in the "/root/.aspnet/https/" folder for a certificate that has the same name as your project.

If I enable tracing using your appsettings.Development.json:

```
      "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Trace ",
          "System": "Trace ",
          "Microsoft": "Trace"
        }
      }
```

I see the error below shown if I start running my sample app without a certificate mounted in the guest container:

```
    root@7afc71f877ce:/app# dotnet helloworld.dll
    dbug: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host[1]
          Hosting starting
    dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer[2]
          Failed to locate the development https certificate at '/root/.aspnet/https/helloworld.pfx'.
    dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer[1]
          Unable to locate an appropriate development https certificate.
    crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
          Unable to start Kestrel.
    System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
    To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, thanks.  However cannot get production scenario to work.  The documentation seems to be incorrect.  When I use the docker run command in the section Windows for Windows containers, I get the error "Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification".

Comment: Ok, I tried to reproduce it on my local and I can trigger that error by setting a path that does not exist on the host or on the guest.

I have a relatively new version of Docker and these are my errors: "Error response from daemon: .aspnet\https%!(EXTRA string=is not a valid Windows path)."

or

"Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification: '/host_mnt/c/Users/Alberto/.aspnet/https:.aspnet/https/': invalid mount config for type "bind": invalid mount path: '.aspnet/https/' mount path must be absolute.".

Comment: One thing that pops in my mind to check, if you are using PowerShell %USERPROFILE% becomes $Env:USERPROFILE?

Comment: No using cmd.  The volume mounting syntax has to be modified on Windows.  the -v somepath:c:\somepath absolutely will not work.  I fought this some time back.  This is very poorly documented on the docker side.  Clearly whoever wrote the document never tried that command.