# Unable to configure ASP.NET HTTPS endpoint in Linux docker on Windows

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, docker, asp.net-core

I'm having issues trying to debug a docker container pointed at the "Production" ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT in Visual Studio. The "Development" environment works fine. I'm trying to debug against a production container because we are having issues with the different appsettings file per environment.

This is my error:

Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.
For more information on configuring HTTPS see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054.

I've looked through a few articles but nothing seems to work when debugging against production. When I remove https from the launchSettings.json the site doesn't run at all.

https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/master/samples/host-aspnetcore-https.md

[Unable to configure ASP.NET HTTPS endpoint in Windows docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52457514/unable-to-configure-asp-net-https-endpoint-in-windows-docker-container)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#trust-the-aspnet-core-https-development-certificate-on-windows-and-macos

Environment:

Windows 10
Linux Containers
ASP.NET Core 3.1

launchSettings:

```
"Docker": {
  "commandName": "Docker",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production",
    "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "https://+:443;http://+:80",
  },
  "httpPort": 51934,
  "useSSL": true,
  "sslPort": 44349
}
```

DockerFile

```
#Depending on the operating system of the host machines(s) that will build or run the containers, the image specified in the FROM statement may need to be changed.
#For more information, please see https://aka.ms/containercompat

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1.2-bionic AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
RUN apt update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt install -y tzdata
RUN apt install -y --allow-unauthenticated \
    libc6-dev \
    libgdiplus \
    libx11-dev \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-bionic AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY src .
RUN dotnet restore "ExampleApp.Web/ExampleApp.Web.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/ExampleApp.Web"
RUN dotnet dev-certs https --trust
RUN dotnet build "ExampleApp.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ExampleApp.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Production

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ExampleApp.Web.dll", "--environment=Production"]
```

[image]

Comment: Were you ever able to find a solution to this?

Comment: I discovered that the final comment in this github issue to resolve this error for me. https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/19359

Answer (score 3):

Some options

Option 1: 
inside the app, configure like so, it should work

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseUrls(YourWebAppUrls)
                .UseKestrel()
                .ConfigureKestrel(options =>
                {
                    options.ListenAnyIP(51934);  // whatever your port
                })
                .UseIIS()
```

---

Option 2:

In your build tasks you can add this to the command line see [here](http://www.waynethompson.com.au/blog/dotnet-dev-certs-https/)

Close your browsers so that they do not cache the certificate because that will cause other issues.

On the commandline run this

```
dotnet dev-certs https --clean
```

then run

```
dotnet dev-certs https -t
```

---

Option 3:
[Self signed Cert](https://www.humankode.com/asp-net-core/develop-locally-with-https-self-signed-certificates-and-asp-net-core)

---

Option 4:
Run these commands from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/docker-https?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

```
dotnet dev-certs https -ep ${HOME}/.aspnet/https/aspnetapp.pfx -p { password here }
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

**Windows using Windows containers
Generate certificate and configure local machine:**

```
dotnet dev-certs https -ep %USERPROFILE%\.aspnet\https\aspnetapp.pfx -p { password here }
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

Run the *Container* Image with Core configured for HTTPS:

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/samples:aspnetapp
docker run --rm -it -p 8000:80 -p 8001:443 -e ASPNETCORE_URLS="https://+;http://+" -e ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=8001 -e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password="password" -e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=\https\aspnetapp.pfx -v %USERPROFILE%\.aspnet\https:C:\https\ mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/samples:aspnetapp
```

Comment: My environment is docker. These are for IIS on local machine.

Comment: Just try it, look at the references they all have Linux machines.

Comment: Development works though. It's only when the environment is pointed at Production.

Comment: hmm.. do you have a reverse proxy or something thats different in prod. whats the setup like.

Comment: Are you on Digital Ocean. I Posted some configurations from ASP core 2.2, try that, The first few options I listed worked when I was hosting there.

The support at Digital Ocean sucks when it comes to Windows containers or ASP Hosting though.

Comment: No not when debugging locally. I'm not on DO.

Comment: Option 3 is no longer available. Please avoid give answers with links.